# distinct of dates in LINQ To Entities?

Tags: linq-to-entities

I have:

```
select distinct 
       to_date(to_char(i.fe_stax, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY') FechaProg,
       a.id_ciud, t.no_ciud 
from itinerario i
where to_date(to_char(i.fe_stax, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY') is not null
```

I want something like this?

```
var tmp = (from itin in db.ITINERARIO
           where itin.FE_STAX != null
               select new 
               {
                 FechaProg = itin.FE_STAX.Value, 
                 IdCiud = itin.EMPRESA_AEROPUERTO.AEROPUERTO.TTCIUD.CO_CIUD, 
                 NoCiud = itin.EMPRESA_AEROPUERTO.AEROPUERTO.TTCIUD.NO_CIUD
               }
          ).Distinct();
```

but I do not format the date column to apply DISTINCT

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are applying distinct not on a date column here but on an anonymous type - this will never work as the type has no concept of equality as it has not been defined for this type.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an IEqualityComparer to make the distinct work where quality is based just on date.  If it was me though, I may try something a little more basic, like such:

```
var tmp = (from itin in db.ITINERARIO
            where itin.FE_STAX != null
            select new
            {
                FechaProg = itin.FE_STAX.Value,
                IdCiud = itin.EMPRESA_AEROPUERTO.AEROPUERTO.TTCIUD.CO_CIUD,
                NoCiud = itin.EMPRESA_AEROPUERTO.AEROPUERTO.TTCIUD.NO_CIUD,
                ToDate = itin.to_date
            }
).GroupBy(item => item.ToDate).Select(group => group.First());
```

Basically, you would have to add a property to your anonymous type that stores the date, group on that date, and then return the first element in each group.